# Loadrunner controller- Users getting failed after attempting certain number of iterations

Tags: controller, loadrunner

Users getting failed after attempting certain number of iterations or after certain specific duration. 
We have sufficient data and Parameter settings is Random each iteration.
No number of iterations is defined in Script’s RTS.
These are just API calls.
Not simulating new user on each iteration.
User base is pretty high almost 1800 users.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3mxw.jpg)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why users are getting out? they should keep on doing the iterations until they end of the execution but they are getting out in midway of the execution.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What are your monitors telling you about the resources that are being locked up at the time the users start failing?

Comment: @Buzzy: we observed few "Error: C interpreter run time error: Action.c (46):  Error -- memory violation : Exception ACCESS_VIOLATION received." errors .
Also few 500 Internal server error but these are app related.

Comment: @JamesPulley: did another round, we stared with 100 user , ramp up after 1st 20 minutes 44 users came out after doing 1800 iterations and 10 minutes later the remaining came out after doing 1800 iterations.

Comment: @Buzzy: Also i checked we have many "Error: Exception was raised when calling abort-cleanup function in extension trans.dll: System Exceptions: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION" also

Comment: So, no resource monitors.  OK, implement those with respect to your architecture.  So, HTTP 500...make sure your code checks for expected positive content results (not just HTTP 200) on every request and branch when the expected positive result is not reached.  The most common cause of an HTTP 500 in a performance test is the lack of checking for expected results which then causes a request which is inappropriate to the state of the application to be submitted.  Notice, you exit after 1800 iterations and your number of users is 1800.  Coincidental?  I suspect you have limited pacing/think time

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the response, Our problem is not the HTTP 500 but the user exiting after 1800 iterations. we have a limited pacing of 4 seconds for the flow.

Comment: I think you will need to open a support ticket to have this analyzed by our support team.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the response, Our problem is not the HTTP 500 but the user exiting after 1800 iterations. we have a limited pacing of 2 seconds for the flow.
Script contains 2 API calls with no think time between them and a data set of 3000 data. we use pacing of 2 seconds and 500 users to achieve TPS of 250.

Earlier i was using 30K data, thought the issue was the large amount of data i am using but i am still facing the same with 3K data.